# Download images from GEE directly to the computer

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have few codes that retreive LANDSAT images, calculate NDVI and then create rasters and then export them to my drive. Mnay times if the raster is too heavy it breaks it into few images.
My question is if there is any way to export images directly to my computer?

This is an example of code which I would like to downliad its' products to the compuer but not to my drive:

```
var geometry=plots;
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
  .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
}

// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-09-12')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .select('B2','B3','B4','B8','QA60')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

var clippedCol=dataset.map(function(im){ 
   return im.clip(geometry);
});

//test if clipping the image collection worked
Map.centerObject(geometry,14);
Map.addLayer(clippedCol.median(), rgbVis, 'RGB');

// Get the number of images.
var count = dataset.size();
print('Count: ',count);
// print(clippedCol);//here I get the error messege "collection query aborted after accumulation over 5000 elements
// print(dataset,'dataset');//the same error here


//function to calculate NDVI
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
  .rename('NDVI')
  .copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
  return image.addBands(ndvi);

};

//NDVI to the clipped image collection
var withNDVI = clippedCol.map(addNDVI).select('NDVI');



// // Test the addNDVI function on a single image.
// var ndvi1 = withNDVI.select('NDVI').mean();


var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};

//get NDVI images




var listOfImages =(withNDVI.toList(withNDVI.size()));


var listOfNumbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,32,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,];



for (var i in listOfNumbers) {
  var image = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(listOfNumbers[i]));
  var toexport=image.visualize(colorizedVis).addBands(image);


  // export
  Map.addLayer(image, colorizedVis, i);
  Export.image.toDrive({
  image: toexport.toFloat(),
  description: i,
  scale:2.5,
  crs:'EPSG:4326',
  maxPixels:1310361348,
  region:geometry.geometry().bounds()

});


 }





//Long-Term Time Series

print(ui.Chart.image.series(withNDVI, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30));
```

Comment: Are the images cropped? Sentinel-2 scenes are organized according to US-Military Grid Reference System (MGRS), you can check `MGRS_TILE` metadata to know this. Each tile is a part of the *cropped* image. If you want all tiles in a single composite, use `mosaic()`

Comment: you can If you have Google drive file stream installed on your computer